# Wpf. Scroll DataGrid inside ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scrollviewer, attached-properties

### Current realization

Hello there.
Currently I have the following application:

[image]

If you can see, when my cursor on blue or red zone I`am scrolling only the main ScrollViewer.

### Expectations

I'am expecting that if I'll scroll with cursor on DataGrid, should be scrolled only the DataGrid. Not the main ScrollViewer.
But currently it works like the following demo:

[image]

### Question

How can I enable the possibility to scroll DataGrid at ScrollViewer?

### Current code

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" PanningMode="Both" Background="Blue"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Padding="0,0,50,0"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" PreviewMouseWheel="DataGrid_PreviewMouseWheel">

    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Height="300"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="True" PreviewMouseWheel="DataGrid_PreviewMouseWheel"
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
        <Rectangle Height="200" Fill="Red"/>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Height="300"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="True" PreviewMouseWheel="DataGrid_PreviewMouseWheel"
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
    </StackPanel>

</ScrollViewer>
```

```
private void DataGrid_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var args = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta);
    args.RoutedEvent = ScrollViewer.MouseWheelEvent;

    if (e.Source is DataGrid)
    {
        DataGrid0.RaiseEvent(args);
    }
    else
    {
        ScrollViewer.RaiseEvent(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try setting [MouseWheelEventArgs.Handled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) to `true` in your `DataGrid_PreviewMouseWheel` event handler to stop other handlers from scrolling

Comment: @LegkovIvan, thank you for your answer.
But I already tried it. Not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove PreviewMouseWheel event from Scrollviewer and DataGrid too.